# How to flip the view vertically on another view iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, core-animation, caanimation

I'm developing an app which contained stack of views and i want that when the user swipes down on a image view this flip and shows another view.Its working but while its flipping vertically it merging with below lying view and showing another view.

Please go through the link , one will comes to know:https://dribbble.com/shots/1667024-Events-deck-animation

In above link,in animation after swipe left and right ,the user will down vertically without merging with below lying views.Please any help how to implement this vertical flip animation as shown in the mentioned link.

I am using the following code to flip veertically for single layer:

```
float duration = 1.0f;
CABasicAnimation* animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.x"];
animation.delegate = self;
animation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:-0.0f * M_PI];
animation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:-1.0f * M_PI];
animation.duration = duration;
animation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeRemoved;
animation.repeatCount =1;
animation.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime();
animation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];
[photo.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"rotationX"];
photo.layer.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.bounds), CGRectGetMidY(self.bounds));
```

Please any one knowsshare it ,I need to implement this animation.

Answer (score 2):

Try using UiView's transitionFromView method with  `UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromBottom` or `UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromTop` for implementing animations on UIView than view's layer.

Like:

```
[UIView transitionFromView:viewToReplace
                    toView:replacementView
                  duration:1
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromTop
                completion:nil];
```

Add this call in the swipe gesture selector method of the `viewToReplace`

For more see this link: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW105

**EDIT**:
May be This will work for you.

```
// Consider flipView as the view that need to flip vertical 
[UIView transitionWithView:flipView
                      duration:1
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromTop
                    animations:^{
                        // flipView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
                        // update to be done with flip
                       } completion:nil];
```

Comment: I tried, but it will make transition for container view ,I required for single view that's why I chosen the CABasicAnimation

Comment: I have a container view with four image views aligned as stack,if user swipe down. the only top imageview should flip vertically.From your code,it flips the container view itself.

Comment: in the swipe selector method you should set the flipView with the view, that you have on the top of the stack, are you managing that?

Comment: flip view is the one that rotate, no other views will be affected.

Comment: The main issue will be here that , top imageview should not merge with below lying view while rotating.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to comment the last line in your code and your view will animate or flip vertically on the same place without merging with the underlying views.